# LWUIT Scroll List issue

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-list

I have 5 `Lists` in my `Form`. They are hidden and when I show one of them, the focus go inside the `List` and the `Form` doesn't scroll.  I want to show all the `List`, navigate across it and keep my `Form`scrolling showing that `List`.Is there any way to make a `List`no scrollable?

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION**

I show a `Form` with a `Button`. When I press this `Button` a `List` is showed  under the `Button`. When the focus enter inside the `List`, the `List`starts to scroll, but the `Form`doesn't, and I can't see the other elements. What I want is...a `List` no scrollable and a `Form`scrollable that let me see the rest of the `List`.

[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]

By munon at 2012-02-03

In the photo, you can see, the `CheckBoxes` are in the `List`. This `List` has a scrollbar but is his scrollbar not from the `Form`.

Comment: Explain more explicitly ; difficult to understand your problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make a list none scrollable but that shouldn't matter. If your form is scrollable and uses the correct layout (e.g. BoxLayout Y), then everything should just work (assuming you revalidate after adding a new list).

Personally I would use Components/Containers rather than lists for a design as elaborate as this. They provide lots of advantages over lists such as more refined focus/touch behavior.